# Método onTaskRemoved() dando erro

Tags: android, task

Tenho uma Activity que extende a AppCompatActivity e nela tenho o seguinte método:

```
 @Override
    public void onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent) {
        NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        mNotificationManager.cancel(notID);
    }
```

O objetivo dele é cancelar uma notificação, caso o usuário feche a aplicação pelo Task Manager. Essa notificação é sempre exibida quando a Activity entra no método `onPause()`.

Ja tentei alterar o método `onDestroy()` mas sem sucesso, pois quando a aplicação é fechada direto no Task Manager, a aplicação não passa pelo `onDestroy()`

Comment: Qual o erro que você tem encontrado? O método simplesmente não funciona ou alguma exceção é lançada? Tem alguma mensagem relevante no logcat?

Comment: @RoneyGomes Ele nem compila, fica um traço vermelho embaixo do `@Override` com os dizeres _Method does not override method from its superclass_  e, caso eu tirar o `@Override` os erros de sintaxe somem, mas na execução não entra dentro do método.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Classe do serviço:

```
public class KillNotificationsService extends Service {

    public static int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1;
    private NotificationManager mNM;
    private final IBinder mBinder = new KillBinder(this);

    public class KillBinder extends Binder {
        public final Service service;

        public KillBinder(Service service) {
            this.service = service;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return mBinder;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        return Service.START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {    }

    @Override
    public void onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent){
        mNM = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        mNM.cancel(NOTIFICATION_ID);
    }
}
```

Método dentro da Activity

```
private void serviceNotification(){
    ServiceConnection mConnection = new ServiceConnection() {
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className,IBinder binder) {
            ((KillNotificationsService.KillBinder) binder).service.startService(new Intent
                    (MontarTimesActivity.this, KillNotificationsService.class));

            NotificationManager mNM = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            mNM.notify(KillNotificationsService.NOTIFICATION_ID, notification().getNotification());
        }

        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName className) {
        }
    };
    bindService(new Intent(MontarTimesActivity.this, KillNotificationsService.class), mConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Você está tendo esse problema porque o método `onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent)` não faz parte de `AppCompatActivity`e nem de qualquer outra classe `Activity`. Esse é um método que faz parte da classe `Service`, conforme você pode conferir na [documentação](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#onTaskRemoved(android.content.Intent)). Portanto, pra poder efetuar o que você quer, será preciso implementar o seu próprio serviço, registrá-lo na sua aplicação e chamá-lo no momento apropriado. Se você nunca trabalhou com serviços antes, este [guia](https://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/guide/components/services.html) em português pode te ajudar a começar.

Além disso, é importante notar que se você definir `android:stopWithTask="true"` na declaração do serviço no `AndroidManifest.xml` então esse callback não será executado e o serviço terminará junto com a aplicação.

Comment: Tomei como referência as respostas desse post e consegui http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12997800/cancel-notification-on-remove-application-from-multitask-panel

Comment: Massa. Nesse caso eu sugiro que você feche a questão ou publique aqui a sua resposta e aceite ela como solução.